# How to disabled style from library css in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I use the react-slick library to make a slider. I have images inside the tag responsible for the slider. Depending on the size of the screen I would like to hide the images but the property slick.css blocks my css style. How could I turn it off?

[image: display block]

Comment: Can you link the library you are using?

Comment: yes, https://react-slick.neostack.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a more specific css selector.
I assume your image has a class .cHgPZg.

If yes you can try the selector

```
.slick-slide img.cHgPZg { dsiplay: none; }
```

If this is not working you can always use the !important; but try to avoid it if possible.

```
.cHgPZg {display: none !important;} // not recomanded
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You have to add a more specific selector in order to overwrite the dominating selector and hide the image. Try walking the selector tree backwards until the selector is specific enough; Something like this:

```
.slick-slider .slick-list .slick-slide img {
    display: none;
}
```